# Eigen Space dimension of Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=J(r_1,r_2,..,r_k)$

which implies that $A$ is in Jordan canonical form with $k$ blocks of each size $r_i×r_i$

I need to show that dimension of eigenspace${}=k$.

i.e. number of blocks

Can I get some help?

Comment: *Hint*: Where do you read eigenvectors in a Jordan block?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't get it. Sorry..

Comment: If you have a block, say, $\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1&0\\0&\lambda&1\\0&0&\lambda\end{bmatrix},$what are the eigenvectors and what are the generalised eigenvectors?

Comment: generalized form of eigenvector is (1,0,0)^T with value lambda.

Comment: so each block has only one eigenvector and hence k eigenvectors can be made for entire matrix. Isn't it right?

Comment: Yes. Note that what you wrote is actually a real eigenvector, and there are also  two generalised eigenvectors. As a conclusion, to a Jordan block  of dimension $k$ corresponds a single eigenvector and $k-1$ generalised eigenvectors.

Comment: Ah.. I see.. Thanks